Rabbit MQ Consumers to same message Context
This situation is happening to me and my team
we have a service that allows people to make investments, redemptions and position search by account, and all of it is fueled by Rabbit Mq but there is a problem happening, sometimes when a few messages are beeing consumed at the same time or very close to it one of them is passed over and not republish in the queue.
for example: If there is 3 messages with the same account, 123, and one of them is consumed before the other one is processed the message consumed falls into limbo
the question is: is there a way to lock the messages with the same account to be consumed until the previous one is processed or republished? for example: consumer1 consumes message1 with account 123 the messsage2 with account 123 will be available to be consumed by consumer2 or consumer3 only when message1 is processed or republished in the queue
